# Do $http call after another $http call in other controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How can I call an `$http.get` in `Portraits` controller just after `$http.get` in `Match` controller finish? I need the `idMatch` to call the others.

```
var app = angular.module('Rugby', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var idMatch = 0;

app.controller('Match', ['$http', '$log', function ($http, $log) {
    var $scope = this;

    $http.get('./lib/data.php?query=getMatches').success(function (response) {
        var lastMatch = response.length - 1;
        idMatch = response[lastMatch].idMatch;
        $scope.date = response[lastMatch].date;
        $scope.local = response[lastMatch].local;
        $scope.visitor = response[lastMatch].visitor;
    });

}]);

app.controller('Portraits', ['$http', '$log', function ($http, $log) {
    var $scope = this;
    this.players = [];

    //I need to have the idMatch before this two calls starts
    $http.get('./lib/data.php?query=getPlayersInMatch&idMatch=' + idMatch).success(function (response) {
        $scope.players = response;
    });

    $http.get('./lib/data.php?query=getPlayersOutMatch&idMatch=' + idMatch).success(function (response) {
        $scope.notConfirmedPlayers = response;
    });
}]);
```

I wasted two days in this right now and it may be so simple...

**UPDATE:** My app just retrieve the data from all the matches, get the data of the last one and show the teams that play in it and the date. Then after that it should retrieve all the players in our team that will play it and show their pictures and names.

Comment: You can put idMatch in a shared service, or you can $broadcast it from a controller to another

Comment: I'm not sure how your application works, would it make sense to just combine the functionality into one controller?  In that case after your call to getMaches returns successfully you can then call the getPlayersInMatch directly.

Comment: I'm starting to sense that we were never really meant to call `$http` methods inside a controller. This looks like a job for `$resource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the requirements of your application we can only assume that you have a valid reason for separating these two controllers.

If the controllers are siblings and have no scope inheritance relationship, your only choice is to broadcast an event via the $rootScope.  However this is bad practice and should be avoided.

If they have an inheritance relationship the child would use $emit (upwards) rather than $broadcast

Please read

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

to understand scope inheritance.

The following sample (not mine) http://jsfiddle.net/VxafF/, is a simple, understandable example.

```
$http.get('./lib/data.php?query=getMatches').success(function (response) {
    var lastMatch = response.length - 1;
    idMatch = response[lastMatch].idMatch;
    $scope.date = response[lastMatch].date;
    $scope.local = response[lastMatch].local;
    $scope.visitor = response[lastMatch].visitor;

    $rootScope.broadcast('matchIDEvent', {'idMatch': idMatch});
});
```

Your Portraits Controller would then need a new function:

```
$rootScope.$on("myEvent",function (event, data) {
    $http.get('./lib/data.php?query=getPlayersInMatch&idMatch=' + data.idMatch).success(function (response) {
        $scope.players = response;
    });

    $http.get('./lib/data.php?query=getPlayersOutMatch&idMatch=' + data.idMatch).success(function (response) {
       $scope.notConfirmedPlayers = response;
    });
});
```

Both controllers also need to have the rootScope injected.